# passing a value to a display function javascript

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I need help figuring out how to pass the value of "div" to a display function i'm working on. Here's my code.

//above i have a constructor function and I declare "newbox", i also get values for my boxes
// displaying the boxes on the page and getting their values works fine

```
  function addBox(newbox) {  
   for (var i = 0; i < newbox.number; i++) {                                 
   var scene = document.getElementById("scene");              
   var div = document.createElement("div");                   
   div.className += " " + "box"; 
   div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
   div.style.backgroundColor = newbox.color;  
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));
   div.style.left = x + "px";
   div.style.top = y + "px"; 
   scene.appendChild(div); 
   div.onclick = display;                          
   //console.log("added"); 
    } 
   return div;                 
  }
```

//function to make the string to pass to the next function

```
  function makeString(name,color) {
  var aString = "name" + "color";
  return aString;
  }
```

//display function that should show an alert when a box is clicked.

```
  function display(e) {
  var a = e.target;
  var string = makeString(a.name, a.color);
  a.onclick = alert(string);
  }
```

So far when I click on a box I get the string "namecolor". I thought by doing "a.name" and "a.color" I could get those values from the target I was clicking on, but that obviously did not work. Also tried passing div directly to display() function, but I didn't figure out how to do that correctly. I'm a beginner, so this could be super obvious, but help is appreciated.

Comment: firstly don't put name and color in quotes.  You are appending the string name and the string color to get namestring

Answer (score 3):

#### addBox

This method doesn't make sense as you are looping in a for loop to create a certain number of divs, but then you only return one?

```
function addBox(newbox) {
  var i, div, scene = document.getElementById("scene");
  for (i = 0; i < newbox.number; i++) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    scene.appendChild(div);
    div.onclick = display;
  }
  return div;
}
```

it would make more sense like this:

```
function addBox() {
  var i, div, scene = document.getElementById("scene");
  div = document.createElement("div");
  scene.appendChild(div);
  div.onclick = display;
  return div;
}
```

#### makeString

As others have stated, don't wrap you vars in quotes as this will mean they are treated as strings, rather than variables.

```
function makeString(name,color) {
  var aString = "" + name + color;
  return aString;
}
```

#### display

You have to assign an anonymous function to an event handler if you wish to keep the value of `string` available so that it can be alerted `onclick`. Just assigning the result of the alert method will mean that the alert will happen immediately and not wait for the click.

```
a.onclick = alert(string);
```

However, this `display` method is still a little confusing because `display` is triggered when clicking on the div. You are then assigning another `onclick` handler which will only fire the next time the div is clicked.

```
function display(e) {
  var a = e.target;
  var string = makeString(a.name, a.color);
  a.onclick = function(){
    alert(string);
  }
}
```

What would make more sense is:

```
function display(e) {
  var a = e.target;
  var string = makeString(a.name, a.color);
  alert(string);
}
```

#### name and color

Also your code doesn't mention where `name` and `color` are set on the div element? do you mean the colour of the text, the colour of the background or some other arbitrary value? Also with `name` do you mean `.nodeName` or something else like an element's `.name` attribute?

If you wanted arbitrary attributes on the div you could use `setAttribute`, so after you've created it, assign the values you want:

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute('name', 'this_is_my_name');
div.setAttribute('color', 'midnight blue');
```

And then retrieve them using `getAttribute`:

```
var string = makeString(a.getAttribute('name'), a.getAttribute('color'));
```

Or as others have stated, if you are expecting to get the current text colour of the div use `.currentStyle.color` and `.getComputedStyle` - far easier however would be to define the colour specifically on the div via `.style.color` which is easier to read back in a cross-browser way.

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.color = 'red';
```

And then to read back:

```
alert( div.style.color );
```

Comment: wow, thank you for taking the time to write this down. i edited my addBox() function to include all of the code. color, name and number are all parameters of newbox. so: var newbox = new Box(name,color,number). I got all of these values from a form and tried to assign them using the for loop, while iterating through the number value. which is the total number of boxes the user chooses to make. i edited my makeString() function. and the onclick event. thanks again!

Comment: @user1876829 No worries, with that extra information it makes more sense -- did you get things working in the end?

Comment: @LemmyTauer Thanks! I do tend to waffle, not sure if that's passion :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple problems in your code.

First, change this:

```
var string = makeString(a.name, a.color);
```

To this:

```
var string = makeString(a.innerHTML, a.currentStyle['color']);
```

Then, change this:

```
var aString = "name" + "color";
```

To this:

```
var aString = name + color;
```

That will give you the contents of the DIV and the current color CSS attribute on the DIV. It's a little unclear from your question exactly what you want to display. If you could clarify what it is that you want to display from the DIV or update your question with your HTML, I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

change `var aString = "name+"color"` to `var aString = name+color` without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function makeString(name,color) {
    var aString = name+""+color;
    return aString;
}
```